# Jar File with External Jars Executes then Doesn't

Tags: java, jar, compilation, libraries

I have a bunch of files that rely on `three external JARs` (Two for emailing [activation and javax.mail], and one for SQL). I can compile it fine, I can pack it into a `JAR` file fine, I test the `JAR` by sending a test email to my email, it works fine yay great! Then, 10-15 seconds later, I try to open the same `JAR`, and poof, the email doesn't send and I get a `ClassNotFound` exception. I have no idea why this happens. I am using IntelliJ as my IDE and I can't get that `JAR-maker` thing to work, so I'm using terminal commands. Here is what I've done as my terminal commands: (I've tested others with same result)

Compiling:

```
javac -classpath .:/lib/connector.jar:lib/activation.jar:lib/mail.jar -d . 
MainPackage/EmailHelper/Emailer.java MainPackage/LoginAndSignup/MainLoginOrSignup.java 
MainPackage/LoginAndSignup/Login/Login.java MainPackage/LoginAndSignup/Signup/Signup.java 
MainPackage/LoginAndSignup/AccountDetails/AccountInfo.java MainPackage/Main/Main.java
```

Jar packaging:

```
jar -cvmf META-INF/MANIFEST.MF CM.jar lib/connector.jar EmailHelper/lib/activation.jar 
EmailHelper/lib/javax.mail.jar MainPackage/EmailHelper/Emailer.class 
MainPackage/LoginAndSignup/MainLoginOrSignup.class 
MainPackage/LoginAndSignup/Login/Login.class MainPackage/LoginAndSignup/Signup/Signup.class 
MainPackage/LoginAndSignup/AccountDetails/AccountInfo.class MainPackage/Main/Main.class
```

A few notes: I have looked at the decompiled `Java` code through the `Jar` file, and all the class files and external `JARs` are all there. Is it the way I compiled it?

Problem: When I compile and package my project, I test it it works fine yay! Then, 10-15 seconds later, I test it again and I get a `ClassNotFound` error. I have written the terminal commands I'm using if helps.

Thanks in advance.

Manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/connector.jar lib/activation.jar lib/mail.jar
Main-Class: MainPackage.Main.Main
```

Comment: Hi, I have a lib directory with all my JARs and a Class-Path entry in the manifest already I just don't know why it works then, poof, it doesn't. Thank you

Comment: I've added the `manifest` file to the original post. The stuff inside the `JAR` file doesn't depend on anything outside of it although it might because I'm not sure if my external `JARs` have anything on the users computer. I don't think it matters where the app is being started because all the things needed are inside the `JAR` file.

Comment: Aha! I see. Thank you!